# Lower arrow within subscript

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, subscripts, math-fonts

I'm using redesigned arrows (for maps, limits, etc.) that look better to me with Lucida Bright fonts than do the defaults.

For the `\tendsto` command, for limits, it seems that I have to explicitly use a `\raisebox{`*negativeAmount*`}{\to}` in the command

```
 \newcommand{\tendsto}{\mathrel{\raisebox{-0.5pt}{\to}}}
```

But while this looks OK in normal math, the arrow is not quite low enough when it appears within a subscript.

How can I cause the amount that the `\to` arrow is lowered for `\tendsto` so to adapt to when it is within a subscript vs. when it is in ordinary math — *without* having to invoke a separate command in the subscript situation?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lucidasmallscale]{lucidabr}
\linespread{1.04}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}        
\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Stealth[scale=1]}}
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=0.4pt}}

%% SAVE OLD DEFS
\mathchardef\oldrightarrowchar=\numexpr\rightarrow-"3000\relax
\mathchardef\oldmapstochar=\numexpr\mapsto-"3000\relax
\newcommand{\oldrightarrow}{\mathrel{\oldrightarrowchar}}
\newcommand{\oldto}{\mathrel{\oldrightarrowchar}}
\newcommand{\oldmapsto}{\mathrel{\oldmapstochar}} 
\newcommand{\oldtendsto}{\mathrel{\oldrightarrowchar}}
\newcommand{\oldrightinf}{\mathord{\oldrightarrowchar}}
%% MY NEW
\newcommand{\basicrightarrow}{\mathrel{\,\tikz[baseline,line width=0.4pt]\draw[arrows=-{Stealth[scale=0.75]},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (1em,0);\,}}
\renewcommand{\rightarrow}{\scalerel*{\basicrightarrow}{\oldrightarrow}}
\renewcommand{\to}{\scalerel*{\basicrightarrow}{\oldrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\barredrightarrow}{\mathrel{\,\tikz[baseline,line width=0.425pt]\draw[arrows={Bar[line width=0.85pt,scale=1]}-{Stealth[scale=0.75]},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (1em,0);\,}}
\renewcommand{\mapsto}{\scalerel*{\barredrightarrow}{\oldrightarrow}}
%% the issue is in following command:
\newcommand{\tendsto}{\mathrel{\raisebox{-0.5pt}{\to}}}
 \newcommand{\shortrightarrow}{\mathord{\tikz[baseline,line width=0.4pt]\draw[arrows=-{Stealth[scale=0.5]},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (0.65em,0);}}
\newcommand{\rightinf}{\scalerel*{\shortrightarrow}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{$\infty$}}}

% test command for the math with arrows:
\newcommand*{\test}[4]{% params: tendsto, to, mapsto, right-infinite %
  \texttt{\textbackslash#1}, \texttt{\textbackslash#2}, \texttt{\textbackslash#3}, and \texttt{\textbackslash#4}:\\[6pt]
  Let $(x_n)_{n \in \N} \csname#1\endcsname x$ in~$X$ where $f \from X \csname#2\endcsname Y$ \& $x \csname#3\endcsname y$;
  that is, $\lim_{n \csname#1\endcsname \infty} x_n = x$%
   \begin{gather*}%
   \lim_{n \csname#1\endcsname \infty} x_n = x \text{ where } f \from X \csname#2\endcsname Y \text{ and } x \csname#3\endcsname y \text{ on } [x, \csname#4\endcsname).\\%
   \lim_{t \csname#1\endcsname x} f(t) = y, \text{ that is,} \quad t \tendsto x \, \implies \, f(t) \tendsto y.%
   \end{gather*}
   }

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\test{oldtendsto}{oldto}{oldmapsto}{oldrightinf}
\test{tendsto}{to}{mapsto}{rightinf}

\end{document}
```

[image: \tendsto arrows in subscripts are too high.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use variable amounts depending on the current math style. The amount should be in `ex` units rather than `pt`, so it adapts to the current font size.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tendsto}{%
  \mathrel{\fix@height\oldrightarrow{-0.0625ex}{-0.03ex}{-0.01ex}}%
}
\newcommand{\fix@height}[4]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\fix@@height{#1}\textstyle{#2}}
    {\fix@@height{#1}\textstyle{#2}}
    {\fix@@height{#1}\scriptstyle{#3}}
    {\fix@@height{#1}\scriptscriptstyle{#4}}%
}
\newcommand{\fix@@height}[3]{\raisebox{#3}{$\m@th#2#1$}}
\makeatother
```

With this definition we have from

```
\noindent
\test{tendsto}{to}{mapsto}{rightinf}

\noindent
$x\tendsto\infty$\qquad
$\scriptstyle x\tendsto\infty$\qquad
$\scriptscriptstyle x\tendsto\infty$

\Large\noindent
\test{tendsto}{to}{mapsto}{rightinf}

\noindent
$x\tendsto\infty$\qquad
$\scriptstyle x\tendsto\infty$\qquad
$\scriptscriptstyle x\tendsto\infty$
```

the following output

[image]

Fine tune the amounts to suit your taste.

Comment: I'm usure what's going on here: is this still basing my new `\tendsto`, as I want to do, on my new kind of arrow constructed via `tikz-arrows`?

Comment: And should I be handling the other kinds of new arrows differently than by using `\scalerel*`?

Comment: @murray I don't use `scalerel`, so I don't know about it.

Comment: Seems to me I want your way of defining `\tendsto`should  use `\to` rather than `\oldrightarrow`, so that it's based on my newly-defined (via `tikz-arrows`) kind of arrow rather than on the original

Comment: @murray To be honest, I didn't really understand too much of all the juggling you make; the method for different amount raising in the various math styles is independent on the particular symbol you use.