# How move tikz arrow down?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

To create a "better" version of `\to` with Lucida Bright fonts — one with a more visible arrow tip that also will harmonize with arrows in `tikzcd` diagrams, I'm starting with a `tikz` arrow, as in the source below.

Close inspection of the greatly enlarged output will show that my `\myto` arrow is slightly higher than the built-in Lucida `\originalto` arrow.

**Question:** How can I lower the shaft of the `\myto` arrow so that its shaft will be at the same height as the original?

**Related:** I asked a similar question in [Lower arrow within subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457415/lower-arrow-within-subscript). The accepted answer there defines and uses a `\fix@height` function that also uses a `\mathchoice` construction. What I don't see is how to combine the construction there with the `\mathchoice` construction I'm already using here, which takes account of the actual current point size.

(Everything I've tried so far manages somehow to change dimensions of the arrow.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Stealth[scale=1]}}
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=0.4pt}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[lucidasmallscale]{lucidabr}
\linespread{1.04}

\mathchardef\originalrightarrowchar=\numexpr\rightarrow-"3000\relax
\newcommand{\originalto}{\mathrel{\originalrightarrowchar}}

\newcommand{\basicrightarrow}{\tikz[baseline,line width=0.3pt]\draw[arrows=-{Stealth[scale=0.55]},yshift=0.625ex] (0,0) -- (0.625em,0);}
\newbox\basicrightarrowbox
\sbox\basicrightarrowbox{\mbox{\basicrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\myto}{\mathrel{%
  \mathchoice
    {\resizebox{!}{\the\fontdimen5\textfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{\the\fontdimen5\textfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{\the\fontdimen5\scriptfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{\the\fontdimen5\scriptscriptfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
}}

\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%          
  \noindent $f \from X \csname#1\endcsname Y$ \quad \texttt{\textbackslash#1}
}

\begin{document}

\test{myto}\\[2pt]\test{originalto}\\
\mbox{}\hspace{-0.425em}$%
\begin{tikzcd} f\from X \arrow{r}{} & Y \end{tikzcd} $ \quad tikzcd

\end{document}
```

[image: \myto arrow too high]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using yshift so you can chaneg it to whatever value you prefer, as that changes the height you can adjust the resizebox to scale to a fraction of 1ex again choose whatever looks right. I didn't have the fonts you used but changed the values a bit to get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Stealth[scale=1]}}
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=0.4pt}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[lucidasmallscale]{lucidabr}
\linespread{1.04}

\mathchardef\originalrightarrowchar=\numexpr\rightarrow-"3000\relax
\newcommand{\originalto}{\mathrel{\originalrightarrowchar}}

\newcommand{\basicrightarrow}{\tikz[baseline,line width=0.3pt]\draw[arrows=-{Stealth[scale=0.55]},yshift=0.5ex] (0,0) -- (0.625em,0);}
\newbox\basicrightarrowbox
\sbox\basicrightarrowbox{\mbox{\basicrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\myto}{\mathrel{%
  \mathchoice
    {\resizebox{!}{.9\fontdimen5\textfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{.9\fontdimen5\textfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{.9\fontdimen5\scriptfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
    {\resizebox{!}{.9\fontdimen5\scriptscriptfont2}{\usebox\basicrightarrowbox}}%
}}

\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%          
  \noindent $f \from X \csname#1\endcsname Y$ \quad \texttt{\textbackslash#1}
}

\begin{document}

\test{myto}\\[2pt]\test{originalto}\\
\mbox{}\hspace{-0.425em}$%
\begin{tikzcd} f\from X \arrow{r}{} & Y \end{tikzcd} $ \quad tikzcd

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record, a factor of `.8` rather than `.9` with the Lucida Bright fonts lowers the tikz arrow to match the built-in one. I didn't try your method because the scale factor will apply to the width as well as the height, but the result overall looks OK to me.